# How to filter various fields

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have a piece of code at the views, i intend filtering all the various fields in the database model called OrderItem.

Here is the code:

```
def search_form(request):

    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        x = request.GET['q']
        q = x.title()

        print q

        x = request.GET['certification_type']
        print x

        items = OrderItem.objects.filter(Q(order_type__iexact=x and order_type__iexact=q) | Q(certification_type__iexact=x and certification_type__iexact=q) | Q(item__iexact=x and item__iexact=q)
         | Q(certification_no__iexact=x and certification_no__iexact=q) | Q(client__user__email__iexact=x and client__user__email__iexact=q) | Q(client__phone_number__iexact=x and client__phone_number__iexact=q)
         | Q(created_on__icontains=x and created_on__icontains=q))


        for x in items:
            for q in items:
                print items 



        return render(request, 'i/search_results.html', {'items':items, 'query':q})
    else:
        return render(request, 'i/search_form.html', {'error':True})
```

but if i try to find items under certification_type, i get empty list [] at the console. i don't know what am missing

Comment: The code you've pasted isn't even valid - `...or Q(client=q))objects.filter()....`

Comment: can u elaborate more what is certification_type means field type

Comment: the certification_type is just a string when the user fills in a form

Comment: @Sayse am getting "invalid syntax" at items = OrderItem.objects.filter( Q(item=q) or Q(certification_type=q) or Q(order_type=q) or Q(certification_no=q) or Q(client=q))objects.filter().values('order_type','certification_no','client','item','signer','certification_type','created_on')

Comment: Is that the problem you're trying to solve? thats not what your question is asking about.

Comment: if i try to find items under certification_type, whichis "Encapsulation", i am suppose to see all the fields that contain Encapsulation

Comment: Just Fixed it. Thanks for all you comments it was helpful